# Bind object's fields/methods

Tags: scala, generics, collections, existential-type, type-bounds

How do you bind object's fields/methods with a type?

I am trying to do:

```
object CRUDable {

  private val allCRUDables = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, CRUDableMeta[_]]()
  def add(crudable: CRUDableMeta[_]) { allCRUDables += (crudable.name -> crudable) }
```

and my compiler sais that:

```
type arguments [_$5] do not conform to trait CRUDableMeta's type parameter bounds [T <: etam.jpa.crud.CRUDable[T]]
```

I need the Map to accept any type of CRUDableMeta[_].

Thanks in advance, Etam.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the liberty to construct a general case, because I don't know CRUD and it doesn't play a role:

```
trait Data[T]
trait Meta[T <: Data[T]] { def name: String }
val all = collection.mutable.Map[String, Meta[_]]()
```

Now the compiler tells you exactly what is wrong with

```
def add(c: Meta[_]) { all += c.name -> c }
```

It says:

```
error: type arguments [_$1] do not conform to trait
       Meta's type parameter bounds [T <: Data[T]]
```

So while Scala lets you construct the `Map` without complaining (honestly I don't know why), you run into the bounds of `Meta`'s type parameter `T` when you try to actually store the value in the map.

The solution is to use either of the following forms. (1) type parameter for the method:

```
def add[T <: Data[T]](c: Meta[T]) { all += c.name -> c }
```

(2) Existential type

```
def add(c: Meta[T] forSome { type T <: Data[T] }) { all += c.name -> c }
```

Don't ask me about (2), I keep forgetting what the existential types are all about... Maybe someone else can offer an insight here as to whether (1) or (2) is better. ([the only answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374610/when-to-use-existential-type-in-scala) suggests that (1) and (2) are pretty much the same, where (1) furthermore allows you to subsequently refer to type `T`. While that is not necessary here, it is still the more readable version, I'd say)